# OpenShift with JBOSS server 7.1.1.Final java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, openshift, jboss7.x

I got this Error when build my app on openshift jboss server 7.

```
2017/03/17 22:02:37,944 WARN  [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-5) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [hibernate-bean.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) [spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305) [spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301) [spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196) [spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753) [spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834) [spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) [spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) [spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) [spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at com.vietcamthai.services.model.dao.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:17) [classes:]
    .....
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindManyToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:2888) [hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindOneToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:3065) [hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1791) [hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:904) [hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:731) [hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:245) [hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222) [hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265) [hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83) [hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418) [hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87) [hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692) [hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724) [hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416) [spring-orm-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:401) [spring-orm-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) [spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) [spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        ... 42 more
....
2017/03/17 22:02:37,964 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/]] (MSC service thread 1-5) Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
2017/03/17 22:02:37,964 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-5) Error listenerStart
2017/03/17 22:02:37,965 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-5) Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2017/03/17 22:02:37,972 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ROOT: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ROOT: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_131]
2017/03/17 22:02:38,022 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.7.170.129:9990
2017/03/17 22:02:38,023 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 52973ms - Started 428 of 549 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 116 services are passive or on-demand)
2017/03/17 22:02:38,179 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "ROOT.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ROOT" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ROOT: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
2017/03/17 22:02:38,180 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ROOT: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ROOT: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
2017/03/17 22:02:38,190 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ROOT" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ROOT: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}}}
2017/03/17 22:02:38,447 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ROOT.war in 266ms
```

and my pom.xml file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>database</groupId>
    <artifactId>database</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>database</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        <org.springframework-version>4.2.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <jackson.databind-version>2.2.3</jackson.databind-version>
        <hibernate-version>5.0.2.Final</hibernate-version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>1.0.0.Final</version> -->
        <!-- <type>pom</type> -->
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->

        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.databind-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- optional -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-proxool</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- End Hibernate framework -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-rev-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Common codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when invoking mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>database</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <additionalProjectnatures>
                                <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                            </additionalProjectnatures>
                            <additionalBuildcommands>
                                <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                            </additionalBuildcommands>
                            <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                            <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.6</source>
                            <target>1.6</target>
                            <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

and my code is working perfectly when I run it in pivotal of spring tool suite.
But it appear Errors on JBOSS 7 of OpenShift. I also try to use JBOSS 6 server but it's still have the same errors.

I try to search many many times on google and see the same error, but I try every solutions that I found on the internet it still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try many way I saw on the internet and the error still occurs when I deploy it to openshift using Jboss 7 server. So the final solution I try is use Wildfly 10. And my code work perfectly.

If Anybody have the same error as me when using openshift and jboss7 as server, try to use another server like wildfly 10. It support java-ee-7 and jdk-8 also